# R Flexdashboard: How to perform data load operation outside the app?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I'm trying to fetch around 55,000 rows from SQL Server using odbc driver. This data load operation takes a long time in isolation as well as while running the shiny app. I've looked for some solutions. One of them is to perform database operations outside the app. But I'm not able to figure out the way to do it for a flexdashboard app.

My Code for loading data is below:

````
```{r include=FALSE}
#Establish connection to ODBC
con <- dbConnect(odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "XXX.XX.XX.XXX",
                 Database = "XXXXX",
                 UID = "USERNAME",
                 PWD    = "pwd",
                 trusted_connection = 'yes',
                 Port = XXXX)



set.seed(12)
```

```{r include=FALSE}
#Fetching Main Data
TBL_VIEW_A<- tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "View_A"))

#Fetching Secondary Data
TBL_VIEW_B<- tbl(con, in_schema("dbo", "View_B"))

#Load Data for Analysis
data <- TBL_VIEW_A %>%  
  select(A,B,C,D,E
         ) %>% as.data.frame() 
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date)
data$f<- data$B+ data$C+ data$D

Sec_Data <- TBL_VIEW_B %>% 
  select(P,Q,R,S,t) %>%
  as.data.frame()
Sec_Data $Date <- as.Date(Sec_Data $Date)
```
````

Comment: You can separate the data munging process to a separate r file and save the result to an rda file, then read in that rda file at the beginning and outside your server logic in the flexdashboard.

Comment: @PaulDong Thanks. Will take a look.